# CSS Animated Images Rotating In Opposite Directions

Tags: css, image, animation, rotation

I'm trying to have one hand rotate one way and the other hand rotate the other way so it looks like the hands are presenting something below.
See codepen https://codepen.io/sadive/pen/QWPWMLG
I can only get the divs rotating in ONE direction, not opposite. How can I solve this?
Only the one on the right is rotating as intended.

```css
#handsleft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  color: white;
  animation: mymove 8s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

#handsright {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  color: white;
  animation: mymove 8s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="handsleft">
  <img src="https://syminadivecom.ipage.com/2024/6-hands-left.png" width="400px">
</div>


<div id="handsright">
  <img src="https://syminadivecom.ipage.com/2024/6-hands-right.png" width="400px">
</div>



<div id="gif" style="margin:auto; clear:both; padding-top:100px;">
  <h3>example below:</h3>
  <img src="https://syminadivecom.ipage.com/2024/6-hands-animate.gif" width="300px">
</div>
```

Comment: You overwrite you animation... set different names to your 2 animations

Comment: Use 2 differnt animation name. As @sfili_81 said you are overwriting your animation

Comment: Thank you @Sfili_81 I gave it two different names but one is still lower than the other: https://codepen.io/sadive/pen/QWPWMLG

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. The hands are already rotating in opposite directions. would you like to make them rotate in the same direction?